# Merging Variable PHP

Tags: php, variables, merge, var

im confuse that...

like example:

```
$Q1 = "hello";
$Q2 = "world";
$Q3 = "StackOverflow";

$i = 1;

while($i < 3) {
  $a = "$Q".$i; //I think this is wrong.    
  echo $a; // i tried ${$a} doesn't work =/

  $i++;
}
```

then output format:

```
$Q1
$Q2
$Q3
```

but there is not output like this:
hello
world
StackOverflow

I want like `$Q + $i` become `$Q1` to answer is: "hello"...

Comment: These are called variable variables or variables with variable names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$varName = 'Q'.$i;
$a .= $$varName;
```

Or just

```
echo $$varName . "<br>\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

To create the variable variable, use:

```
$a = ${'Q'.$i};
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo $Q1 . $Q2 . $Q3;` will output what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
$a = '';

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
  $a .= ${'Q' . $i};

echo $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is simply printing the string '$Q1', '$Q2' and '$Q3'. In PHP you use dynamic variable names this way:

```
<?php
$Q1 = 'hello';
$Q2 = 'world';
$Q3 = 'StackOverflow';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo ${'Q' . $i};
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP does support variable variable names, denoted using `$$`. This will do what you want.

```
$qvar = 'Q'.$i;
$a = $$qvar;
```

However, this is considered *very* poor practice -- almost as bad as using `eval()` (and for similar reasons).

The correct answer would be to create an array of `$Q`, and referencing array elements;

```
$Q = array(
        "hello",
        "world",
        "StackOverflow")

$a = $Q[0] . $Q[1] . $Q[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. When you have double quoted strings, and you put a dollar sign and something else in it, it  interprets it as a variable. (it also escape things like `\n`)

Example

```
$test = "hi";
echo "$test world"; //This outputs hi world
```

In your case, `$Q` doesn't exist. The default PHP behaviour is to ignore that error and just puts out nothing. This is why it's recommended to report all problems with your code. Check out 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for details.

Solution to your problem would be using single quoted strings. do `$a = '$Q'.$i;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$Q = array("hello", "world", "StackOverflow");
foreach($Q as $w) {
    echo $w;
}
```

If you can't do something like this then you will need to use dynamic variables:

```
$var = 'Q' . $i;
echo $var;
```