# Merging Variable PHP 2

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, merge

reference from: [Merging Variable PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391494/merging-variable-php)

I have problem with $_POST getting blank null after click 'submit' button..

my code:

```
$temp_var = "_POST['text_".$id."']";

echo $$temp_var;
```

output: blank

Comment: Tip: Enable error reporting, PHP will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Variable variable names do not work for array access, only for the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, did you make sure your form saves to the POST using `method="post"`?

Second of all, why'd you use variable variables?

You could simplify this to

```
echo $_POST["text_$id"];
```

Comment: is that possible? i thought first generate from other variable then to put to merge variable.

Comment: @user453089: Why should it not be possible? The index is a string and you can create it in any way you want to. PHP is doing variable parsing in double quoted strings, so that is completely fine. I suggest you read some more documentation before you do any further "adventures" ;)

Comment: Nope, completely possible. You could use various ways to do this. `$_POST['text_'.$id]` works as well, for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
$temp_var = $_POST["text_".$id];

echo $temp_var;
```